# Non inverting op-amp gain LTspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, ltspice

[image]

This configuration of OPA134 in LTspice has have a gain of 1.5 and hence should have a voltage output of 3. However it does not. Why?

Spec: http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa4134
Spice model: http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa4134
in design and development tab

I may be missing something in the spec, however any other op amp I use produces an output of 3V, so it seems weird for this one to produce an extra amount of voltage. If it is an integer gain, then the output voltage is as expected, however any float gain then it produces a bit more voltage than necessary.

Comment: up those resistor values by 10:1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your negative power supply voltage is 0V, you can't put 2V in the inputs:

[image]

Comment: ah, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the OPA134 opamp does not work properly with the input voltage too low for it. Maybe the SIM program does not have its model. I also agree that the resistor values are WAY TOO LOW!